# Is there a way to use require function in browser without using Browserify, RequireJs or similar packages

Tags: jquery, node.js

Is there any way to use `require()` Node js function on client side without installing additional tools or packages like `Browserify` and `RequireJs`?

I am working on a website and I need to update mongodb collection with button click.  When I import my mongo model in `controller.js`  i got refference error:

> require is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use require() Node js function on client side without installing aditional tools or packages like Browserify and RequireJs.

No.  The browser does not natively support `require()` so to use a function with that name, you'd have to add some code that supports that.  There are dozens of loaders one can get for the browser, but all would be adding additional tools or packages to your web page which you expressly asked to avoid.  So, without one of those, you cannot use `require()`.

> I am working on a website and need to update mongodb collection with button click, when i import my mongo model in controller.js i got reference error: require is not defined.

Your database and controller run on a server somewhere.  They do NOT run in the browser.  So, you do not import or require their code into the browser.  That code won't run in the browser and the database is not local to the browser either (it's on some server somewhere). Instead, you  either send a form or send an Ajax call from the browser to your server and deliver with the ajax call or form some instructions (in the URL) and/or some data (in the form) and then the code on your server that handles that URL talks to your database/model to carry out the operation.

Here's a [reference on Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) calls from the browser.  The general idea is that you create a route (e.g. an URL) on your server that is expressly for this button click or expressly for the operation that this button represents.  If you're adding data to the database, then you probably make it a POST route handler and you probably post a form from the browser to that URL.  FYI, the simplest way to send a form to your server is by using `<form>` tags in your HTML and a submit button.  But, you can also gather the data in your browser-side Javascript and send an Ajax call to the server with client-side Javascript.

Comment: One note: you _can_ use require in the browser, it's just not performant, and as you say, won't let you connect to a database. See for example this project https://github.com/maple3142/require-unpkg

Comment: @SamH. - Did you read my first paragraph?  Already addressed.  There are dozens of loaders one can add to get require-like functionality.  None satisfy what the OP asked ***"without installing aditional tools or packages like Browserify and RequireJs"*** and none solve their database problem either.

Comment: The package I link to has no build step, you can just add a script tag. It uses unpkg - it's kinda clever.

Comment: @SamH. - As do more than a dozen other loaders for the browser.